# vmware app loader crashed while installing vmware-tools for windows guest

Tags: vmware-player, vmware-tools

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 and vmware player 5.0.2. I'm trying to install Win 7 as guest and when it tries to install vmware-tools, the vmware app loader crashes with the `error updating software component. Any ideas whats wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem. 
What I did was to simply run vmplayer as root to let it install kernel module :

```
sudo vmplayer
```

If you have problem compiling network module, here's what to do : http://communities.vmware.com/message/2182440#2182440